# How to change image and highlight text on scroll via Scroll hijack?

Tags: reactjs, animation, scroll, gsap, framer-motion

Hi guys need your help to implement an animation which I am trying to build. I want to change the image and highlight the text related to that image respectively while scrolling.

[image]

My only challenge is how to stop scrolling out of this section since the images are stacked on top of each other. I somehow want to hijack the scroll behaviour and change the image instead of scrolling down the screen I want to change the image that are on viewport. And as soon as the 4 feature image is rendered then scrolling should go down the further div content(as usual behaviour).
Please help me how to achieve this, any good library or tutorial which explains this. BTW I am using React.